# Entity Framework Code First Many to Many creating duplicate rows

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern, code-first

**My issue turned out to be having two context's. I reworked my code a bit to only have one context and my issue went away.**

I have a User which has a list of UserContact's which itself has a ContactOption. Its a fairly simple 1 to many, many to 1 with the UserContact table in the middle.

If I pull the user out of the db and create a new UserContact, but set the ContactOption to an existing item (which I've pulled out of the db), when I SaveChanges, entity framework creates a new ContactOption in the database that is essentially a duplicate of the one I added to the UserContact (with the exception that it gets a new id).

I've battled with this for several hours and can't figure this out. Any ideas?

I am using a Repository pattern for my database queries, but I have ensured they are sharing the same context.

I pull the user out of the database with this:

```
var user = _context.Users.Include("UserContacts.ContactOption")
              .Where(id => id == 1);
```

And contact options are pulled out with:

```
var co = _context.ContactOptions.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
```

And I add the ContactOption to the UserContact like so:

```
var contactOption = _context.ContactOptions.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == someId);

var contact = new UserContact { ContactOption = contactOption  };
contact.Data = "someData";

user.UserContacts.Add(contact);
```

My model looks like this:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserContact> UserContacts { get; set; }
}

public class UserContact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public User User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ContactOption ContactOption { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class ContactOption
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code where you associate the ContactOption to the UserContact

Comment: Justin, I've updated the question as asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run your code and got the exact expected results: A new row in *UserContacts* table with the existing UserId and ContactOptionId, so I am not sure what's happing in there, but you can try to explicitly have FKs in UserContact object so that you'll have full control over how Code First inserts records for you. For that, you need to change UserContact as follows:

```
public class UserContact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // By Convention these 2 properties will be picked up as the FKs: 
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ContactOptionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public User User { get; set; }        
    [Required]
    public ContactOption ContactOption { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can change your code like this:

```
var contactOption = _context.ContactOptions.Find(someId);
var user = _context.Users.Find(1);

var contact = new UserContact 
{ 
    ContactOptionId = contactOption.Id,  
    UserId = user.Id,
    Data = "someData"
};

user.UserContacts.Add(contact);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I don't know whether to mark your answer as correct or not. It did help lead me down where I needed to go, but I didn't solve it the way you did. My issue turned out to be I had two context's because in my ModelBinder I was spinning up a new repository. I fixed it with some DI goodness and my problem is good now!

Comment: Thanks for your update and yes, I knew that the problem is somewhere else since like I said, I literally copy paste your code and it worked as expected for me. My intention by posting this answer was to show you how we can drop down explicit FKs, so that we are not bound to any unknown code first conventions anymore and we can make sure that the code will be working the way we want it to work.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct since it did help me. I'll also edit my question to point out that creating two context's was my issue.

Answer (score 1):

My issue turned out to be having two context's. I reworked my code a bit to only have one context and my issue went away. Thanks to Morteza Manavi for pointing me in the right direction.